# How to scrape content from nested div html

Tags: python, web-scraping

I tried to get price ($50.56) info from this link: https://www.google.com/search?biw=1600&bih=758&output=search&tbm=shop&q=McKleinUSA+17564+N+Series+ARIA+%28Khaki%29&oq=McKleinUSA+17564+N+Series+ARIA+%28Khaki%29&gs_l=products-cc.12...26051.26051.0.27263.1.1.0.0.0.0.71.71.1.1.0....0...1ac.2.64.products-cc..0.0.0....0.AxAVt6XRExI#spd=15005512733707849930

but I keep get nothing.

So I get link info from excel file using openpyxl and use requests and bs4 to **scrape** the info.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

wb = load_workbook(filename = "test.xlsx")
ws = wb.get_active_sheet()

html = ws['A2'].hyperlink.target

source = requests.get(html).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
test = soup.find('span', attrs = {'class': "O8U6h"})
```

Comment: Those classes are dynamically generated everytime you load a page. So, better is to use their API. @Jay

Answer (score 0):

Classes are dynamic but there is a constant id and you can use the relationship of the b tag to this

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?biw=1600&bih=758&output=search&tbm=shop&q=McKleinUSA+17564+N+Series+ARIA+%28Khaki%29&oq=McKleinUSA+17564+N+Series+ARIA+%28Khaki%29&gs_l=products-cc.12...26051.26051.0.27263.1.1.0.0.0.0.71.71.1.1.0....0...1ac.2.64.products-cc..0.0.0....0.AxAVt6XRExI#spd=15005512733707849930')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('#ires b').text)
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the class names change. I opened the link myself and couldn't find an element with class `O8U6h`.

Comment: This should be an comment, not an answer @Maxxik CZ